# Bio Perl: code to split paired end data?

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, bioperl

I am a beginner with bioinformatics and I have been working on a little Bio Perl code to split my paired end MiSeq data (currently in 1 fastq file) into 2 files, each file containing one end of the pair. The different ends of the paired end reads can be distinguished by a **1** or a **2** after the space in the fastq header. The file follows a typical fastq format, example from using "head" in the command line:

```
@M00763:6:000000000-A1U80:1:1101:12620:1732 1:N:0:1
TTATACTC
+
@A@AA@A@
@M00763:6:000000000-A1U80:1:1101:12620:1732 2:N:0:1
T
+
E
```

I have written a code trying to target the 1 or 2 in the header using a match. Although I am using Bio::SeqIO perl does not seem to be recognizing the fastq format, and I keep getting this error:

```
MSG: Could not guess format from file/fh
STACK: Error::throw
STACK: Bio::Root::Root::throw /sw/lib/perl5/5.12.3/Bio/Root/Root.pm:472
STACK: Bio::SeqIO::new /sw/lib/perl5/5.12.3/Bio/SeqIO.pm:389
STACK: SplitPairedEndReads.pl:7
```

Can someone help me find/fix my error? The information available from BioPerl website indicates that Bio::SeqIO should be able to recognize fastq format.

Here is the code I have written:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use Bio::SeqIO;
use Bio::SeqIO::fastq;


$seqout1 = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => ">peread1.fastq" -format => "fastq",);
$seqout2 = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => ">peread2.fastq" -format => "fastq",);

$seqio_obj = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => "AIS351_Strin1edit.fastq", -format => "fastq",
                         -alphabet => "dna" );
$seq_obj = $seqio_obj->next_seq;

while ($seq_obj = $seqio_obj->next_seq) { 
    $name = $seq_obj->desc; if($name=~ / 1:/) {$seqout1->write_seq($seq_obj);
     } else { $seqout2->write_seq($seq_obj); 

    }
}
```

Thanks for your help and your patience with my beginner knowledge.

~Al

Answer (score 2):

You need to add commas between all list items in your calls to `new`.  Change:

```
$seqout1 = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => ">peread1.fastq" -format => "fastq",);
$seqout2 = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => ">peread2.fastq" -format => "fastq",);
```

to:

```
$seqout1 = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => ">peread1.fastq", -format => "fastq",);
$seqout2 = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => ">peread2.fastq", -format => "fastq",);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to not use BioPerl for Fastq data because it is incredibly slow (see my comments below). You can use [Pairfq](https://github.com/sestaton/Pairfq) for this task because this is one of the things it was designed for (full disclosure: I'm the author). Here's how it would work:

```
pairfq splitpairs -i AIS351_Strin1edit.fastq -f AIS351_Strin1edit_1.fastq -r AIS351_Strin1edit_2.fastq
```

In my benchmarks, this is about 300X faster than doing the equivalent task with BioPerl. For example, I measured that it takes 465 seconds to read 1 million Fastq records with Bio::SeqIO, while the above code can do it in about 1.5 seconds. If you have 500 million records, that is a difference in 64 hours vs. 11 minutes. That is why it is strongly discouraged to use BioPerl for NGS data. I'm not bashing BioPerl because I use it everyday, but be aware of this issue.

About the error in your comments, the BioPerl parser does not like what is on your '+' line.  There must be nothing after the '+' or it must match the sequence header. It's hard to say specifically without seeing the real data, it could also be a line ending problem or something else.

EDIT: You need to put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of every script. Also, it is a good idea to test if a file exists before trying to do anything with it (like trying to read it with BioPerl). About your last question, I suggest you read up on the [FASTQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) format. You can't just remove lines from the record or else it won't be valid FASTQ. A minor point is you don't need to `use Bio::SeqIO::fastq;` because `Bio::SeqIO` will handle loading the appropriate class.

What you posted does not look like real data so it's not easy to say what is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for this. As I added in my update, part of why I was writing this was to improve my programming skills, and because I had a problem that needed solving. I will likely continue trying to make my own code work, or at least run without error messages. But I will also likely use your Pairfq, as I do need reliable split reads for some genome gap closing software.

Comment: @user2852013 I updated my post to address your questions. In summary, you need to improve your script by following best practices and show a snippet of real data that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve what you're after with this snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

my @array = ('@M00763:6:000000000-A1U80:1:1101:12620:1732 1:N:0:1
TTATACTC
+
@A@AA@A@',
'@M00763:6:000000000-A1U80:1:1101:12620:1732 2:N:0:1
T
+
E');

foreach (@array){
        if (/\s+1:/) {
            print "1st pair: $_\n"; # You could redirect this to first.OUTFILE
         }
        if (/\s+2:/) {
            print "2nd pair: $_\n"; # You could redirect this to second.OUTFILE
         }

}
```

Which prints:

```
1st pair: @M00763:6:000000000-A1U80:1:1101:12620:1732 1:N:0:1
TTATACTC
+
@A@AA@A@
2nd pair: @M00763:6:000000000-A1U80:1:1101:12620:1732 2:N:0:1
T
+
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a good approach. This type of data typically consists of millions or even billions of lines. Reading that into an array and looping over it is a very bad idea. You are using what was provided by the OP so, in theory it works, but in practice it's just not a good approach.